# Thread Working Directory

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

By definition, multiple threads of a single program share their working directory. Do you know if there is a way to have each thread in a dedicated working dir ? Maybe a specific library ?

Note : target language is c++

Comment: Working directory is *per process*. If you want a separate thread to have its own working directory you have to use processes and not threads.

Comment: Maintain your own per-thread working directory and prepend it to any relative path you access.

Comment: do you have to use the working directory? maybe you can use the path itself. if you just need the path for example as string, you can handle it by your own.

Comment: Thx for replies ; In fact the application I use is multithreaded and call an external app in the thread. As there are I/O a specific working dir is needed for each thread. I'm currently emulating it with string but was wondering if other solution exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The working directory is an environment property that's fixed for a given process.  You probably want to emulate a *working directory* concept for each thread by simply having a thread specific string that holds a different directory for each thread.

Comment: Another option is to use the `openat(dirfd, ...)` and related functions. This allows you to keep a per-thread file descriptor to each thread's working directory instead of a string. This has the advantage of performing path verification and keeping the directory alive as long as you don't close the file descriptor.

Answer (score 10):

This concept doesn't exist on every operating system, but it does for Linux and Mac OS at least.

On Linux, create your thread with `clone` with `CLONE_THREAD` and without `CLONE_FS`. Alternatively, create a thread normally and use `unshare` with `CLONE_FS`. Then, use `chdir` or `fchdir` normally.

On Mac OS use `pthread_chdir_np` or `pthread_fchdir_np`. These calls have sparse documentation, but are available since 10.12. The [Chromium source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/process/launch_mac.cc#24) indicates that this concept exists since 10.5, but you have to use the syscall directly.

Most of the time you will want to prefer the `*at` family of calls, but there are some situations where it isn't possible to use them--for example, `connect`ing or `bind`ing a Unix domain socket.